# C# Disable MenuStrip items shortkeys

Tags: c#, locking, menustrip

I have a question about MenuStrip in .NET (C#). I wonder how best to set the entire menu to

> enable = false

(also with all menu tree elements). It's about locking the shortcuts in the menu. Is there a simpler solution than using a foreach loop nested in another foreach loop?
You want to lock all windows and all controls (including keyboard shortcuts) for the duration of the program execution.
My code:
`foreach (var c in f.Controls.OfType<MenuStrip>())
 {
        foreach (var z in ((ToolStripItemCollection )c.Items).OfType<ToolStripMenuItem>())
        {
            if (z.HasDropDown)
            {
                ChangeStateItem(z.DropDownItems, enabled);

            }
            else
            {
                z.Enabled = !enabled;
            }
         }
 }`

Comment: How you could operate a menu whose Enabled property is *false* does boggle the mind.  Do share how you did that.

Comment: @HansPassant I updated my post.